# JQuery: How to Update Datetimepicker Based on Another DatetimePicker & input

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to make a simple Date Calculator That Calculate Date For Last Installment like the following example:

Start Date `DD/MM/YYYY` = `14/06/2016`

Number of Monthly Installments = `48`

Last Date `DD/MM/YYYY` = `14/06/2020`

I used Bootstrap date picker to do that.Based on the `Start Date Datepicker` and `Number of Monthly Installments` will calculate and output inside `Last Date Datepicker`.

Hear Is My source Code:

```js
var current = new Date( $("#textdatetimepicker1").datepicker('getDate').getDate()
                        $("#textdatetimepicker1").datepicker('getDate').getMonth(), 
                        $("#textdatetimepicker1").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear());

var newdate = new Date(new Date(current).setMonth(current.getMonth()+1+ parseInt($("textinst1").val()));

$("#textdatetimepicker2).val(newdate.getDate()+"/"+(newdate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+newdate.getFullYear());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Last Installment Date Calculator</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
          $('#textdatetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
         }); 
         
         $(function () {
          $('#textdatetimepicker2').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
         });   
          
      </script> 
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Last Installment Date Calculator</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Start Date </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <div class="input-group date">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                              </span> 
                              <input type="text" name='textdatetimepicker1'  id='textdatetimepicker1' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">     
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;"> Number of Monthly Installments</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textinstl" id="textinstl" placeholder="Enter Number" >          
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">End Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <div class="input-group date">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                              </span> 
                              <input type="text" name='textdatetimepicker1'  id='textdatetimepicker2' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">     
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```

Please Help me to solve this,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change to

var newdate = new Date(new Date(current).setMonth(current.getMonth()+1+ parseInt($("textinst1").val()));

Comment: Thanks @Punja Solanki.  I edit your code, But still it didn't worked.Can you please check my code.Thanks